# How do I add a phone number to a contact using Qpython3

Tags: android, qpython3

Im using Qpython3 on Android 4.2.2. Im currently able to list the latest sms from a particular contact and extract a 10 digit phone number. I want to update a contact's phone number with this number.

How should I do this ?

To be more precise, I want to be able to:

1. Access the contact list.
2. Update contact phone number with this phone number

Is this possible with Qpython3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it in console because you can communicate with the interpreter directly